# Polymer structure in PPCHTEX - how to make big brackets?

Tags: context, brackets, chemistry

I'm trying to draw polymer structure using PPCHTEX under ConTeXt packages, my current code is

```
\starttext
\startformula
\setupchemical[scale=small,width=fit]
\startchemical
\chemical[ONE,SB3,SB7,SB5,SB1,Z0,Z3,Z7,Z5][C,CH_3,CH_3,O]
\chemical[MOV1,ONE,Z0][O]
\chemical[MOV1,ONE,SB3,SB7,SB5,SB1,Z0,Z3,Z7,Z1][C,CH_3,CH_3,CH_3]
\chemical[MOV5,MOV5,MOV5,MOV5,ONE,SB3,SB7,SB5,SB1,Z0,Z3,Z7,Z5][C,CH_3,CH_3,CH_3]
\chemical[MOV1,3OFF1,3OFF1,OPENCOMPLEX]
\chemical[MOV1,MOV1,CLOSECOMPLEX]
\stopchemical
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

the problem is, that brackets produced by `OPENCOMPLEX` and `CLOSECOMPLEX` are too small, I have also tried using `\Bigg\lbrace` and `\Bigg\rbrace` instead, but it also produces too small brackets

Is there any way, how to make correct, big brackets?

Comment: Can you post an image of the output that you get. My output is [shown here](http://i.imgur.com/G9yZJD3.png). Do you want the brackets to be bigger than these? To change the brackets, you can change `\definechemicalsymbol[opencomplex] [\mathematics{\Bigg[}]` to something else.

Comment: @Aditya that's what I get, too. The brackets should include the `CH_3` groups... also the vertical bonds are ending at `H` atoms (which is wrong). They should arrive at the `C` atoms.

Comment: I would suggest posting on the context mailing list. There are no ConTeXt users using chemistry here.